# Filter array of objects with same id, but different value in other key

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, filtering

I’m having an array of objects with keys Id and type. I’m trying to filter for duplicate with the same id but different type, if id is the same and different type, I’d like to keep the type HD and filtered out the one with type SD, I’ve tried nested filter and findIndex, but that didn’t work. I’m kinda stuck on the filtering logic.

Attempted:

```
const filteredArr = arr.filter((a, index, tmp) => tmp.findIndex(b => a.id === b.id ? b.type === “HD”) === index);
```

Array:

```
const arr = [
    {
        id: "123",
        type: "HD",
    },
    {
        id: "123",
        type: "SD",
    },
    {
        id: "1234",
        type: "HD",
    },
    {
        id: "12",
        type: "SD",
    },
];
```

Can you guys please suggest a solution for filtering this array. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: First of all, please present example code that is not full of errors. (Yours currently is, due to the `“` all over the place.)

Comment: Items that have no ID duplicate are to be kept in the result, yes? So anything with type `HD` can be kept in any case, and only if the type is `SD`, you will have to check if there is a corresponding `HD` element or not.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, I’m not sure how to implement that logic to remove the SD type after checking for corresponding HD

Comment: Did you try using a for loop?

Comment: Yeah, I tried for loop, but how would this be implemented without for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), we create a map with id as key and value as each item. If same id is seen again and type is not "HD" we override the current value.

```js
const arr=[{id:"123",type:"HD"},{id:"123",type:"SD"},{id:"1234",type:"HD"},{id:"12",type:"SD"}];

const unique = Object.values(
  arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (!acc[curr.id] || acc[curr.id].type !== "HD") {
      acc[curr.id] = curr;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {})
);

console.log(unique)
```